# SDDM error module org.kde.plasma.core not installed

Tags: kde, sddm

I have installed KDE in the /opt prefix and when I try to use different themes in SDDM like breeze or Sweet-Mars I always get the error saying that the main module
“org.kde.plasma.extras” and module “org.kde.plasma components” are NOT installed.
Could anyone please give a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem and I was able to fix it by installing [plasma-framework](https://github.com/JingOS-team/plasma-framework).
I'm using an Arch distribution called Garuda Linux, so I just had to run `sudo pacman -S plasma-framework`.